# Can C++ assignment operators be free functions?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, non-member-functions

I'm trying something like this:

```
Foo & operator=(Foo & to, const Bar &from);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
E2239 'operator =(Foo &, const Bar &)' must be a member function
```

Are there limitations on which operators can/cannot be defined as Free Functions, and if so, why?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The assignment operator must be a non-static member function and must have exactly one parameter:

> An assignment operator shall be implemented by a non-static member function with exactly one parameter (C++03 13.5.3/1).

`operator()`, `operator[]`, and `operator->` must also be implemented as non-static member functions.

Class-specific `operator new` and `operator delete` (and variants thereof) must be implemented as static member functions (note that these are implicitly static, even if they are not declared with the `static` keyword).

Comment: Any further reasons for doing so? It make sense for the operator= to be a member function, after all, it is one of the `three` copy control functions(namely copy constructor, operator= and destructor). But why for others?

Comment: @zoujyjs operators must have access to internal member variables (possibly private) ones. Free functions won't have such access.

Comment: @iheanyi But we can define the the free function as a friend of the class

Comment: @A.Joe You're correct, that was unclear. Those operators gain access to member variables via the implicit this pointer. A free function would necessarily need to be passed a pointer or reference to the object. Which means the language would necessarily need to have a specific argument order for such methods so that the object pointer could be passed correctly. And the programmer would be responsible for correctly writing all combinations const/non-const versions of these methods. That seems like a error prone waste of time versus simply using member functions already built into the language.

Comment: iheanyi - that argument (pun intended) also applies to all of the mathematical operators that need "Correct ordering" and full access (via friend) to private member functions.

Answer (score -1):

It cannot.

The reason, I guess, has to do with copy constructor. They have very similar semantics, and, you cannot define a copy constructor outside of a class just like other constructor. So, they didn't want to separate the twins far apart (to avoid the twins paradox:).

P.S. What's a shame in C++, is that you cannot add a member to existing class. There's no low-level reason for that. If it would be possible, you could decouple header and cpp dependencies by not declaring private functions in the class definition header.

Comment: If what you are talking about is adding members after the class definition is complete, there certainly are reasons for that. You can't add virtual members later on because by the time the class definition is done the compiler MUST know how big the object (including vtable!) is. Adding non-virtual members outside the class definition would make 'private' pointless because anyone would be able to add members that examined/modified private data. In the context of C++ as a whole, it would break much of what they were trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, first could be good for adding public members. Second, more importantly, it would only require a "friend" or some kind of forward declaration in the class definition, which would help decouple dependencies.

Comment: I don't follow your point about the 'shame' in C++. If you really want to 'add' something to an existing Class, why not just create a subclass? Instead, if what you intended is to 'modify' the original class after it's been fully implemented, I don't think that's the way C++ works.